# Using App.Config from Command Line for C# Programs

Tags: c#, configuration, log4net, command-prompt

I am learning log4net and currently testing out how to use App.Config for XMLConfiguration.

The problem is that I do not have a .NET IDE such as Visual Studio 2008 or Express Edition at office (don't get me started on why/how :-))

I need to compile and run my code where log4net reads the configuration settings from App.Config. How do I do it?

My C# code is as follows.

```
public class BasicXMLConfiguration
{
    public static void Main (string [] args)
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        log4net.ILog log = 
                     log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(BasicXMLConfiguration));
        log.Info("beginning of loop");
        for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
        {
            log.DebugFormat("Loop Count is {0}", c);
        }
        log.Info("looping ends");
    }
}
```

My App.Config is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
    </configSections>

    <log4net>

        <!--
        <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.SimpleLayout" />
        </appender>
        -->
        <!-- Never, ever use the FileAppender. Instead, use the RollingFileAppender -->
        <!--
        <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
            <file value="C:\My_Code\Log4NetTutorials\Log_Files\log-file.txt" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <encoding value="utf-8"/>
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.SimpleLayout" />
        </appender>
        -->
        <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <file value="C:\My_Code\Log4NetTutorials\Log_Files\log-file.txt" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <rollingStyle value="Size" />
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
            <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
            <staticLogFileName value="true" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.SimpleLayout" />
        </appender>
        <root>
            <level value="ALL" />
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
        </root>

    </log4net>

</configuration>
```

My command that I use is this

```
csc BasicXMLConfiguration.cs /r:log4net.dll
```

It compiles fine. However, when I run the exe as

```
BasicXMLConfiguration.exe
```

I get the following error.

```
 log4net:ERROR XmlConfigurator: Failed
 to find configuration section 'log4net' in  the application's
 .config file. Check your .config file for the <log4net> and <
 configSections> elements. The configuration section should look
 like: <section n ame="log4net" 
      type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net"/>
```

How do I make it to reference the App.Config?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to rename `app.config` to `name_of_your_exe.config`. <strike>Suppose your console application name is Log4NetTest.exe then rename `app.config` to `Log4Net.exe.config` and it will be fine.</strike>

As name of your program is `BasicXMLConfiguration.exe` so rename `app.config` to `BasicXMLConfiguration.exe.config` and it will work.

Comment: @TheVillateIdiot: Aaargh! So, it was all that needs to be done. With a Visual Studio IDE, they will automatically create the AppName.exe.config and copy over the contents, whereas without an IDE, I have to manually do it.

Comment: @Kanini - I have only sympathy for you. I cannot imagine why your office would not allow you access atleast to VS Express if you need to use .Net for your work - Hope you are raising hell about it. I would if i were you :-)

Comment: @InSane: As mentioned elsewhere, I am a Support Engineer learning stuff on my own in b/w office work and so no software, no admin rights on my PC. At home, I have Visual Studio Express Edition...so at least the evenings and weekends are a breeze. Thanks for the sympathy though...

Comment: @Kanini - Wasnt aware of the background...now that makes perfect sense! Learning something in b/w work -NICE! More power to you! I wish i could gee myself up enough to do that!!